# HBASE schema design for instant message

Tags: hadoop, schema, hbase

We have been implementing an instant message service and want to use HBEASE to store message history (and using redis to caching ongoing conversation). The incoming message for a user looks like

1. Userid (to whom)
2. time
3. message body (combined with from, message body ....)

Regarding Schema design:
Option A: one message per row
    Row key:  md5(userid) + timesample 
    column/valye:  null / message

Option B: one user per row
    Row key: md5(userid)
    column/valye:  time / message

could you help me to figure out pro and cont? thanks
chatting type include: peer-2-peer, group chating

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know Facebook has done a great job on message system use hbase; Maybe these links will help you:http://www.slideshare.net/brizzzdotcom/facebook-messages-hbase

http://sites.computer.org/debull/A12june/facebook.pdf